# Android AVD emulating 1920x1080 Full-HD screen

Tags: android, screen, screen-resolution, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to setup an AVD with Full-Screen resolution (1920x1080), but I only have a blank screen when I start it. I tried to increase the RAM size to 2048 Mb (2Gb) without success.

1280x720 Works fine. Is this the biggest resolution for an AVD device?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it working either, so my guess is that it's *not currently supported*. Shame, as we'll soon start seeing devices with full HD resolution screens.

**Edit:** With r19 of the Android SDK, it seems to be working now. But it's *very* buggy and crashed on me after some time. It requires GPU emulation as well.

Comment: I didn't updated yet to r19. I'll let you know when I test it. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't work for me, even with GPU emulation :( 1280x720 doesn't work also :(((

Comment: any updates on this?  i'm using ADK v21, and don't see any 1080p devices listed in the AVD dialog.  do you need to create an AVD via the command line for higher resolutions?  hoping to get started on something for OUYA, which is aiming for 1080p/1080i/720p...

Comment: Nope, the emulator is bugged. I ended up buying a real device with a high screen resolution.